# Using NSDictionary with added WebAPI Parameters

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'll preface by saying that I'm a little new to swift and have only taken a couple introductory courses that have lead me to building/modifying my current app. I've been having a bit of an issue with the login function on my app. I recently made some minor changes (adding a couple fields to the to the API and to the front end app to match, one being category) and I have started to see an error stating that there was an uncaught exception due to attempting to insert a non-property list object before the app crashes. I have been since trying to change the structure (using chain ifs and guard) and Type (to NSMutableDictionary) as well as setup some logic to catch the Null value that looks to be being passed with no luck.

This is the JSON plus error from the console:

```
 Attempt to set a non-property-list object {
    imagePath = "<null>";
    email = "xxxx@xxxx.com";
    firstname = xxxx;
    id = 1;
    lastname = xxxxx;
    category = 1;
    message = "Logged in successfully";
    status = 200;
    username = xxxxxx;
 } as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key parseJSON
 [7286:636470] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object {
     ava = "<null>";
     email = "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com";
     firstname = xxxx;
     id = 1;
     lastname = xxxxx;
     category = 1;
     message = "Logged in successfully";
     status = 200;
     username = xxxxxx;
 } for key parseJSON'
```

This is the setup I have for the object.

```
 //stores all information about current member
 var member : NSDictionary?


 @UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

 var window: UIWindow?

 // image to be animated
 let backgroundImg = UIImageView()

 // boolean to check is erroView is currently showing or not
 var infoViewIsShowing = false


 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    // load content in member var
    member = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "parseJSON") as? NSDictionary

    // if member has been logged in/registered, keep them logged in
    if member != nil {

        let id = member!["id"] as? String
        if id != nil {
            login()
        }

    }


    return true
 }
```

This is an example method that I'm using to get/use the JSON for this:

```
    // if text is entered

        // remove keyboard
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        // shortcuts
        let username = usernameTxt.text!.lowercased()
        let password = passwordTxt.text!

        // send request to API
        // set url
        let url = URL(string: "http://xxxx.xxx/xxxx/login.php")!

        // request url
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        // POST to the API
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        // append body to url
        let body = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"

        // append body to request
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)

        // launch session
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            // if there's no error
            if error == nil {

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    guard let parseJSON = json else {
                        print("Error while parsing")
                        return
                    }

                    // remove keyboard


                    let id = parseJSON["id"] as? String

                    // successfully logged in
                    if id != nil {

                        // save member information from host
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(parseJSON, forKey: "parseJSON")
                        member = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "parseJSON") as? NSDictionary

                        // go to home page
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
                            appDelegate.login()
                        })

                    // error
                    } else {

                        // get queue to send issue info to member
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            let message = parseJSON["message"] as! String
                            appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                        })
                        return

                    }

                } catch {

                    // get queue to send issue info to member
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        let message = "\(error)"
                        appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                    })
                    return

                }

            } else {

                // queue to send issue info to member
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    let message = error!.localizedDescription
                    appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                })
                return

            }
```

The field that is returning the null value is a VARCHAR field in the DB. All other fields, except ID and Category (which are both INT), are VARCHAR as well. If there is any other needed information please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the method I was using was only applicable in older versions of swift. I have since updated the code to parse json using:

```
 member = parseJSON
```

And now it looks to be working as intended.